# Trying to automate a specific sequence in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

Below I will list 2 sets of vectors one being index values the other being solutions to the corresponding index value: The two vectors below are not used in code; they are here only to represent the input & output relationship of the function below.

```
std::vector<int> index { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... };
std::vector<int> result { 1, 5, 13, 25, 41, 61, 85, ... };
```

---

I'm trying to write either a for loop or a while loop that will calculate the result based on the index value above for example I have a function that accepts an integer as the index, and returns an int the result:

```
int calculate( int index ) {
    int result = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i <= index; i++ ) {
        // calculate here.
    }

    return result;
}
```

So if someone enters 1 into the function it will return 1; 2 will return 5, 3 will return 13, etc.

I notice that there is a common multiple of 4 added to each addition step in the calculate, but I'm having trouble expressing that within a for loop.

For example iteration 1 = 1; next iteration is 1 + 4 = 5, then the next is 5 + (2*4) = 13, then 13 + (3*4) = 25, etc.

My current attempt is as follows:

```
int calculate( int n ) {
    int total = 1;

    if ( n == 1 )
        return n;

    for ( int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        total += i * 4;

    return total;
}
```

Which appears to be giving me the correct values.

I would like to know if this is a good solution to this or if there is a better approach.

Comment: Why not express it as `(i-1)*4 - 3`?

Comment: You don't need a loop at all.  This is just a math problem.  If you figure out the formula you can just solve for the number you want

Comment: @Ron I don't need map I was only using the 2 vectors as illustrations as for the expected input and outputs of the function. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Nelfeal When I tried your expression it was giving me the values: {-7, -3, 1, 5, 9, 13, 17} which is not correct.

Comment: why do you have the `if` in the loop? it doesn't depend on the iteration and can be moved before the loop

Comment: @vu1p3n0x If I have it before the loop yes it will return from the function first but I don't think that matters if it is within or outside the loop.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x actually when I moved the if outside of the loop it was giving me a result of {1,1,5,13, 25,41, 61} which is not correct.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x my apologies: moving the if outside of the for loop does work; it was in my main when going through a for loop to test values is where I had my error: I was indexing from `[0,7)` instead of `[1,7]`.

Comment: I think the expression you want is pow(i, 2) + pow(i-1, 2).

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to reconize the regular pattern and get a formula for it.  If you plot the points that you have you see that they look like they form a nice quadratic curve.  If you use a online Quadratic regression Calculator like [this one](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/14059932254941) you can enter in the data and find the formula.  In this case you get

```
y = 1 - 2x + 2x^2
```

So, all you need to do is take the number they want into x and solve and you get your result.  That would look like

```
int index;
// get index from user
int result = 1 - (2 * index) + (2 * index * index);
// display result
```